# Way to concatenate Array of structs

Tags: apache-spark

I have a column that contains array of structs. It looks like this:

```
 |-- Network: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Signal: string (nullable = true)
```

This is just a small sample, there are many more columns inside the struct than this. Is there a way to take the arrays in the column for each row, concatenate them and make them into one string? For example, we could have something like this:

```
[["example", 2], ["example2", 3]]
```

Is there a way to make into:

```
"example2example3"?
```

Comment: which Spark version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming having a dataframe `df` with the following schema:

```scala
df.printSchema
```

[image]

`df` with sample data:

```scala
df.show(false)
```

[image]

You need to first explode the Network array to select the struct elements Code and signal.

```scala
var myDf = df.select(explode($"Network").as("Network"))
```

Then you need to concat the two columns using the concat() function and then pass the output to the collect_list() function which will aggregate all rows into one row of type array<string>

```scala
myDf = myDf.select(collect_list(concat($"Network.code",$"Network.signal")).as("data"))
```

Finally, you need to concat into the required format which can be done using concat_ws() function which takes two arguments, the first being the separator to be placed between two string and the second argument being a column with array<string> type which is our output from our previous step. As per your use case, we don't need any separator to be placed between two concatenates strings hence we keep the separator argument as an empty quote.

```scala
myDf = myDf.select(concat_ws("",$"data").as("data"))
```

All the above steps can be done in one line

```scala
myDf= myDf.select(explode($"Network").as("Network")).select(concat_ws("",collect_list(concat($"Network.code",$"Network.signal"))).as("data")).show(false)
```

[image]

If you want the output directly into a String variable then use:

```scala
val myStr = myDf.first.get(0).toString
print(myStr)
```

[image: ex11ex22ex331]

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called spark-hats ([Github](https://github.com/AbsaOSS/spark-hats), [small article](https://dev.to/zejnilovic/working-with-nested-structures-in-spark-4c97)) that you might find very useful in these situations.

With its use, you can map the array easily and output the concatenation next to the elements or even somewhere else if you provide a fully qualified name.

#### Setup

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import za.co.absa.spark.hats.Extensions._

scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- info: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- drivers: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- carName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- carNumbers: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- driver: string (nullable = true)
 |-- teamName: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- team1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- team2: string (nullable = true)


scala> df.show(false)
+---------------------------+------------------------------+
|info                       |teamName                      |
+---------------------------+------------------------------+
|[[RB7, 33, Max Verstappen]]|[[Redbull, rb], [Monster, mt]]|
+---------------------------+------------------------------+
```

#### Command you are looking for

```scala
scala> val dfOut = df.nestedMapColumn(inputColumnName = "teamName", outputColumnName = "nextElementInArray", expression = a => concat(a.getField("team1"), a.getField("team2")) )
dfOut: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [info: struct<drivers: struct<carName: string, carNumbers: string ... 1 more field>>, teamName: array<struct<team1:string,team2:string,nextElementInArray:string>>]
```

#### Output

```scala
scala> dfOut.printSchema
root
 |-- info: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- drivers: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- carName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- carNumbers: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- driver: string (nullable = true)
 |-- teamName: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- team1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- team2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- nextElementInArray: string (nullable = true)

scala> dfOut.show(false)
+---------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
|info                       |teamName                                            |
+---------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
|[[RB7, 33, Max Verstappen]]|[[Redbull, rb, Redbullrb], [Monster, mt, Monstermt]]|
+---------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
```